# Dynamic object creation and release

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have a class that instances some other classes. It's working to control their lifespan, or supposed to ;) A root class managing others which contain events and are subviews of the root view.

I have a lot of graphics involved per view and need to clear things out before loading the next.

Any idea how to unload the current subview and how to load the next subview, while maintaining a named reference to it to use in event handling, from a "touches ended" method?

Thanks
// :)

Comment: do you want to seamlessly swap subviews? transition? scroll?

Comment: I can not understand why you need to keep receiving events from a subview that is being unloaded?

Does the loading of the "next view" take so much time that the user would want to cancel?

Are you creating soething like the Weather or stock application, where you want the current visible screen + the two potential next screens to the left and right to be loaded as well. But not the other potential 20 pages?

Comment: Seamlessly swap subviews seems closest to what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to dump the old subview and hold a handle to the new one, this is actually pretty easy. You want something like this:

```
@interface YourView : UIView
{
    // Create an ivar in your class
    UIView *_subview;
}

// Propertize it as retain to take care of most of the heavy lifting
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *subview;

@end


@implementation YourView

// Map the ivar to the property
@synthesize subview = _subview;

// Call this to put in a new subview
-(void) switchToNewSubview:(UIView*)newSubview
{
    // Remove the old subview, set the new one, and if the new one isn't nil
    // add it as a subview
    [self.subview removeFromSuperview];
    self.subview = newSubview;
    if(newSubview)
        [self addSubview:self.subview];
}

// Don't forget to nil out the subview on dealloc to release it
-(void) dealloc
{
    self.subview = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```